# Getting unrecognized property exception though the property has been mentioned

Tags: java, exception, jackson, json

I am getting the below exception when I try to read the string message coming in.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "EventID" (class org.json.JSONObject), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: {"MessageType": "EventSubscription","MessageData": {"EventID": ["ProximitySensorInRange", "ProximitySensorOutOfRange", "BarcodeBarcodeScanned", "RFIDRFIDScanned", "EXTERNALRFIDEXTERNALRFIDScanned", "ButtonsButtonPressed", "TestClientEvent", "ApplicationInteractionDetected", "ProductAdditionMethodBarcode", "ProductAdditionMethodRFID", "ProductAdditionMethodSearchAndAdd", "KohlsOfferKohlsCashUsed", "KohlsOfferGiftCardUsed", "KohlsOfferPromoCodesUsed", "SearchInputKeyedIn", "SearchInputVoice", "KubeUsageTime", "ProductAdditionMethodRecommendation", "ProductAdditionMethodUPCSearch"]}}; line: 1, column: 65] (through reference chain: com.kube.dataobjects.HostEventObject["MessageData"]->org.json.JSONObject["EventID"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:51)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:731)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:915)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1292)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1270)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:247)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:118)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:538)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:106)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:242)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:118)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3051)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2146)
at com.kube.websocketserver.KubeWebSocketServer.onMessage(KubeWebSocketServer.java:80)
at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer.onWebsocketMessage(WebSocketServer.java:469)
at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.decodeFrames(WebSocketImpl.java:368)
at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.decode(WebSocketImpl.java:157)
at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer$WebSocketWorker.run(WebSocketServer.java:657)
```

This is how im reading the message.

```
hostEvent = mapper.readValue(message,HostEventObject.class);
```

This is my HostEventObject class.

```
public class HostEventObject {

public static final String MESSAGETYPE_SUBSCRIPTION = "eventsubscription";
public static final String MESSAGETYPE_EVENTFIRED = "eventfired";
public static final String MESSAGETYPE_FIREEVENT = "fireevent";

@JsonProperty("APIVersion")
private String APIVersion;

@JsonProperty("EventTime")
private String EventTime;

@JsonProperty("MessageType")
public String MessageType;

@JsonProperty("MessageData")
public JSONObject MessageData;
}
```

Below given is my JSON string message.

```
  {
   MessageType: "EventSubscription",
   MessageData: {
       EventID: ["test1","test2"]
   }
 }
```

Why am I getting this exception? I have read the similar questions but i am not making mistakes of spelling nor can I ignore this property. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessageData is of type [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) which doesn't have a field called EventID. Possibly you meant to put a different class here?

This is your JSON

```
 MessageData: {
   EventID: ["test1","test2"]
 }
```

Which requires the datatype for Message Data has an EventID field which is some kind of List / Set / Array or other Collection of Strings . But what we have is -

```
 @JsonProperty("MessageData")
 public JSONObject MessageData;
```

**UPDATE** Looks like there is a Jackson module for JSON org: see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-json-org. To register the module you can use this :-

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 mapper.registerModule(new JsonOrgModule());
```

Comment: won't it take Messagedata as a JSON object and read the EventID value? When I wrote this in C# using Newtonsoft I declared it as a JObject and I didn't get any error. Please advice.

Comment: It looks like not. Groovy JSON deserialization can give you more dynamic behaviour similar to what you are expecting. There might be a module for Jackson that also supports it, but from the error message this not supported out of the box.

Comment: Updated answer with reference to JSON.org module for Jackson, which should give you the dynamic behaviour you are after. Seeting Message data to be a Map<String,List<String>> would probably also work.

Comment: Or use `JsonNode` for Jackson's own tree model rather than `JSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your POJO is missing a property EventID.
You can solve it 2 ways

1. Add the property in java POJO.
2. Put the code to ignore above property that can be achieved 2 ways:

   a. Mark the POJO to ignore unknown properties

   ```
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
   ```

   b. Configure ObjectMapper that serializes/De-serializes the POJO/json as below:

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapper =new ObjectMapper();    
   mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
   ```